# Java: Read metadata from procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, metadata

I am looking for a way to get metadata from an Oracle store procedure, such as input/output parameters and their types.

I did try `DESC` but it is not working:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("desc pack.procname");
while ( rs1.next() ) { 
System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
}
```

Any ideas on what approach to use to get the input/output parameters?

Thanx for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following statement:

```
select *
from user_arguments
where package_name = 'PACK' and object_name = 'PROCNAME';
```

Depending on the schema the package belongs to, you might need to use the view _ALL_ARGUMENTS_ or _DBA_ARGUMENTS_ instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code block to fix the issue.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(conn.getCatalog(),
                      null,
                      "procedureNamePattern",
                      "columnNamePattern");

while(rs.next()) {
  // get stored procedure metadata
  String procedureCatalog     = rs.getString(1);
  String procedureSchema      = rs.getString(2);
  String procedureName        = rs.getString(3);
  String columnName           = rs.getString(4);
  short  columnReturn         = rs.getShort(5);
  int    columnDataType       = rs.getInt(6);
  String columnReturnTypeName = rs.getString(7);
  int    columnPrecision      = rs.getInt(8);
  int    columnByteLength     = rs.getInt(9);
  short  columnScale          = rs.getShort(10);
  short  columnRadix          = rs.getShort(11);
  short  columnNullable       = rs.getShort(12);
  String columnRemarks        = rs.getString(13);

  System.out.println("stored Procedure name="+procedureName);
  System.out.println("procedureCatalog=" + procedureCatalog);
  System.out.println("procedureSchema=" + procedureSchema);
  System.out.println("procedureName=" + procedureName);
  System.out.println("columnName=" + columnName);
  System.out.println("columnReturn=" + columnReturn);
  System.out.println("columnDataType=" + columnDataType);
  System.out.println("columnReturnTypeName=" + columnReturnTypeName);
  System.out.println("columnPrecision=" + columnPrecision);
  System.out.println("columnByteLength=" + columnByteLength);
  System.out.println("columnScale=" + columnScale);
  System.out.println("columnRadix=" + columnRadix);
  System.out.println("columnNullable=" + columnNullable);
  System.out.println("columnRemarks=" + columnRemarks);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this was copied and pasted from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetStoredProcedureSignature.htm

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using JDBC, my preference would be to use the JDBC metadata API to retrieve this information rather than querying the Oracle data dictionary directly.  [DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the generic JDBC method to get the parameters for a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using JDBC directly, you can use my open source [SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com/) API, which creates plain old Java objects from database metadata.

Comment: returns http 404

Comment: Fixed URL to website